# Strongly typing the output of a c# method

Tags: c#, f#, c#-to-f#

I have a c# function that has a method signature like this: `public bool SerInto(out string result)`. I am trying to call this function to get the resultant string from this method. How do you call this? I want data to be of the type string. Is there a way to strongly type this variable?

Is this correct?

```
let string dataString
ds.SerInto(dataString)
```

How do I get dataString to be the output string of this function

Answer (score 7):

F# can see the `out` parameters tupled with the return value.
So you should be able to call the C# function like this:

```
let (resultBool, dataString) = ds.SerInto()
```

Which is a really nice feature. More about this [here](https://luketopia.net/2014/02/05/fsharp-and-output-parameters/).

Comment: If you are going to use the result directly, a useful approach is: ``match ds.SerInto dataString with | true, resultString -> workWith resultString | _ -> handleError ()``

Comment: Yes, that's further explained in the blog I linked. Thanks!

Comment: I think you might need to remove the parameter of `SerInfo` - if the method has just one `out` argument.

Comment: True, I'll remove it.